# Hamel basis: equivalence of two definitions

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm a little bit confused and would like you help with clarification:

In class I learned this following definition of Hamel basis:
Let $V$ be a vector space.
$X=\{v_a\}_{a\in A }$ would be called Hamel basis if for every $x \in V$ there is a **unique** representation of $x$ as a finite linear combination of members of $X$.

But on the interenet and literature the common definition replaces the uniqueness with demanding that $X$ is independent.

I tried to figure out why the internet's definition leads to my definition. **and would love if you could help me understand**

My thoughts were that if I assumed two different forms of linear combinations i'd look at the difference between them, which is 0, and use the indepndence to derive that the coefficints must be the same. my problem was that the combination don't have to be with the same vectors! (I mean, obviously they have, but I don't know how to justify that).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your argument is correct, you just need to realize that you can always add vectors with $0$ coefficients, thus you can assume both expressions for a given vector use the same finite subset of vectors from the basis. The details are very standard.